# rating is applying for all the components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm applying star rating to my react app.

so I have lists of star components. Once I click on rating it's applying for the all components.

Like I do star rating to first food, then it gets apply for all foods also.

I want to handle each food rating independently.

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong ?

befor rating
[image]

after rating for one food
[image]

here is my..

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Rating } from 'react-simple-star-rating'
import Star from './Start';

export default function App() {
  const [category, setCategory] = React.useState("Indian");
  const [rating, setRating] = React.useState(3);

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setRating(value);
  }

  const Food = {
    Indian: [
      {
        name: "Misal Pav",
        description:
          "Misal pav is a popular Maharashtrian street food of usal (sprouts curry) topped with onions, tomatoes, farsan (fried savory mixture), lemon juice, coriander leaves and served with a side of soft pav (Indian dinner rolls). The sprouts curry is made from moth bean sprouts. This misal recipe is a tasty and filling vegan dish that can be served as breakfast, lunch or brunch.",
        rating: 5,
      },
      {
        name: "Vada Pav",
        description:
          "Vada pav is a savory dinner roll stuffed with fried mashed and spiced potato fritters. It is a popular vegan street food snack eaten in Mumbai and rest of Maharashtra. This dish is full of flavors and various textures!",
        rating: 1,
      },
      {
        name: "Masala Dosa",
        description:
          "Masala Dosa / dosey / dosai is a variation of the popular South Indian dosa which has its origins in Tuluva Udupi cuisine of Karnataka. It is made from rice, lentils, potato, fenugreek, ghee and curry leaves, and served with chutneys and sambar. It is popular in South India.",
        rating: 1,
      }
    ],
    Chinese: [
      {
        name: "Noodles",
        description:
          "Chinese noodles vary widely according to the region of production, ingredients, shape or width, and manner of preparation. Noodles were invented in China, and are an essential ingredient and staple in Chinese cuisine. They are an important part of most regional cuisines within China, and other countries with sizable overseas Chinese populations.",
        rating: 2,
      },
      {
        name: "chilly chicken ",
        description:
          "Chilli chicken is a popular Indo-Chinese dish of chicken of Hakka Chinese heritage. In India, this may include a variety of dry chicken preparations.",
        rating: 2,
      },
      {
        name: "Manchurian",
        description:
          "Veg Manchurian is a tasty Indo Chinese dish of fried veggie balls in a spicy, sweet and tangy sauce. ",
        rating: 2,
      }
    ],
    Italian: [
      {
        name: "Pizza",
        description:
          "Though a slab of flat bread served with oil and spices was around long before the unification Italy, there’s perhaps no dish that is as common or as representative of the country as the humble pizza.",
        rating: 3,
      },
      {
        name: "Pasta",
        description:
          "pasta, any of several starchy food preparations (pasta alimentaria) frequently associated with Italian cuisine and made from semolina, the granular product obtained from the endosperm of a type of wheat called durum, and containing a large proportion of gluten (elastic protein).",
        rating: 3,
      },
      {
        name: "Lasagna",
        description:
          "Lasagna is a wide, flat pasta noodle, usually baked in layers in the oven. Like most Italian dishes, its origins are hotly contested, but we can at least say that’s its stronghold is in the region of Emilia-Romagna, where it transformed from a poor man’s food to a rich meal filled with the ragù, or meat sauce.",
        rating: 3,
      }
    ]
  };
  const handleChangeButton = (cat) => {
    setCategory(cat);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setCategory(category);
  }, [setCategory, category]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        <img
          className="logo"
          src="data:image/png;base64,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"
          alt="Good Food"
        />
        Good Food
      </h1>
      <p>Checkout my Favourite food items here ...</p>
      <div className="btn-container">
        {Object.keys(Food).map((cat, i) => (
          <button
            key={i}
            className={category === cat ? "active" : ""}
            onClick={() => handleChangeButton(cat)}
          >
            {cat}{" "}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <h2>List</h2>
      <div className="list-container">
        {Food[category].map((foodie, i) => (
          <div className="list-item" key={i}>
            <Star
              count={5}
              size={40}
              value={rating}
              activeColor={'red'}
              inactiveColor={'#ddd'}
              onChange={handleChange} />
            <h5>{foodie.description}</h5>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are getting Star component's `value` props from one source which is `rating`.

You need to have an individual value for each Star components.

Replace your Star component with:

```js
    <Star
              count={5}
              size={40}
              value={foodie.rating}
              activeColor={'red'}
              inactiveColor={'#ddd'}
              onChange={handleChange} 
    />
```

Edit:
Edit:
You also need to put the Food object inside a useState so you can edit the ratings for each food categories.

ex:

```
const [food, setFood] = useState({
    Indian: [
      {
        name: "Misal Pav",
        description:
          "Misal pav is a popular Maharashtrian street food of usal (sprouts curry) topped with onions, tomatoes, farsan (fried savory mixture), lemon juice, coriander leaves and served with a side of soft pav (Indian dinner rolls). The sprouts curry is made from moth bean sprouts. This misal recipe is a tasty and filling vegan dish that can be served as breakfast, lunch or brunch.",
        rating: 5,
      },
      {
        name: "Vada Pav",
        description:
          "Vada pav is a savory dinner roll stuffed with fried mashed and spiced potato fritters. It is a popular vegan street food snack eaten in Mumbai and rest of Maharashtra. This dish is full of flavors and various textures!",
        rating: 1,
      },
      {
        name: "Masala Dosa",
        description:
          "Masala Dosa / dosey / dosai is a variation of the popular South Indian dosa which has its origins in Tuluva Udupi cuisine of Karnataka. It is made from rice, lentils, potato, fenugreek, ghee and curry leaves, and served with chutneys and sambar. It is popular in South India.",
        rating: 1,
      }
    ],
    ...
```

and to set Rating you can do:

```js
const setRating = (type: string, food: string, rating: number) => {
        setFood((prevFood) => {
            return {
                ...prevFood,
                [type]: prevFood[type].map((foodData: any) => {
                    if (foodData.name === food) {
                        return {
                            ...foodData,
                            rating
                        }
                    }
                    return foodData;
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I can do that...but how can i update rating on each click..

Comment: @sanjK You also need to put the Food object inside a useState so you can edit the ratings for each food categories. Check my edit.

Comment: okay..so i then i just need to setFood on start onlclick?

Comment: @sanjK to set rating you can check on my new Edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are updating you state rating, and using this state in all your lists.

```
         <Star
          count={5}
          size={40}
          value={rating} // <-----  state that get's updated
          activeColor={'red'}
          inactiveColor={'#ddd'}
          onChange={handleChange} />
```

Instead you need to update the FOOD object. One way would be you can code your onChange such that it finds the element for which you selected starts, and based on that it can update the ratings property and then you can use that rating propery in  component.

```
        <Star
          count={5}
          size={40}
          value={foodie.rating} <-- since you will update the FOOD object you'll get desired result.
          activeColor={'red'}
          inactiveColor={'#ddd'}
          onChange={handleChange} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update rating independently via `useState`

Here you don't have any unique id so i find name.

key refers to `food[key]` ,
ob refers which rating has to updated just pass entire object, like `food[key][position]`

```
    const handleUpdateRating = (key, ob) => {
    setFood((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData ,
      [key]:prevData.[key].map((obj) =>
        obj.name === ob.name ? {...obj , rating:ob.rating + 1} : obj
      )
    }))
  };
```